# Multiple PDF in one CiviRule

Tags: civirules

Is it possible to generate and send several .pdf files with CiviRules "send PDF" function? I want to send an invoice and a certificate that have different templates.

I could send several emails but one email with 2 attachments sounds better. :-)

regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much a CiviRules question but more a PDF API question. At this point it time I do not think this is possible. But I know we have 1 party interested in this, you might want to contribute too?

Comment: What kind of contribution are you thinking of? financial, time, development?

Comment: Merging 2 templates into one .pdf would also be sweet but it's also more a PDF API question.

Comment: Contribution: what are you offering and what would work best for you? Potentially financial :-). What you can do at the moment is have 1 template for the email and another template for the attached PDF, did you play with that?

Comment: it seems that the last version of PDFApi offers now a multiple PDF option https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pdfapi. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can create many pdfs from one webform submission and then send them by civirules. Look up FillPDF extension for drupal.

Comment: hi Emeryk! thanks for your answer, I'll check FillPDF. Regards,