# How to use the new Pdf.Createmulti in CiviRule?

Tags: civirules, pdf

Since [version 2.9 recently released](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/pdfapi) it is now possible to send multiple PDF but I can't find the option when setting a CiviRule 2.16? I can just select 'Send PDF'

[image]

but then there is no way to select multiple PDF.

[image]

Has anyone already succeeded?

EDIT: This question is related to these two other ones:
[Multiple PDF in one CiviRule](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/34306/multiple-pdf-in-one-civirule) and [Share development costs](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37631/share-development-costs-in-order-to-have-multiple-pdf-in-civirule)

Answer (score 2):

After asking Jaap from Civicoop, maintainer of the extension, it seems that the option of sending multiple pdf from a civirule is not yet possible. It's meant to be used from the API v3 interface. But with small additional development, it would be easy to have it as an option in CiviRule.

Comment: i think you should link to your other question