# Share development costs in order to have multiple PDF in Civirule

Tags: civirules

Who could be interested to share the funding for the extra development needed to send multiple pdf with one CiviRule?

Let's say you have a new member and you want to send him/her one welcome message with a personalized receipt and a special certificate. Imagine you could create a Civirule to merge them from your templates and send them for you using the PDF API.

According to the developer of the extension, it would be a small work.

Send PM if you're interested, because we are!

Comment: if you haven't already done so, you might want to ask this at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/town-square

Comment: good idea! not yet done